TypeError: Attempted to wrap executeRead which is already wrapped
I am trying to debug this issue where my test is failing because it is not able to stub one of the methods, I went through all the different answers in stackOverflow for the similar topic, But None worked. Also this is the only test file where i am stubbing this method, not able to figure out what the issue
const { expect } = require('chai');
const { createSandbox } = require('sinon');
const neoMethods = require('../../../../../src/services/neo');

const clients = require('../../../../../src/services/neo/clients');

describe('getSpecificViewClients', () => {
  let sandbox;
  let executeReadStub;
  beforeEach(() => {
    sandbox = createSandbox();
    executeReadStub = sandbox.stub(neoMethods, 'executeRead');
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    sandbox.restore();
  });

  it('should return specific view clients in order', async () => {
    const expectedQueryResult = [
      { name: 'Client A', id: 1 },
      { name: 'Client B', id: 2 },
      { name: 'Client C', id: 3 },
    ];

    executeReadStub.resolves(expectedQueryResult);
    const result = await clients.getSpecificViewClients();

    expect(result).to.deep.equal(expectedQueryResult);

    expect(executeReadStub.calledOnce).to.be.true;
  });
});


Show the code under test and the debugging details. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
